# MYSQL: Selecting the three lowest priced for each vendor in a table

Tags: mysql, select, min

struggling with what should seem to be a simple select. I have a, offers table that has prices, vendors and skus. Multiple vendors can sell the same sku, and also the same vendor can sell the sku more than once. I need the three lowest priced offers from each vendor for a particular sku.

```
offers
+-----+--------+-------+
| sku | vendor | price |
+-----+--------+-------+
| abc | vend_a | 1.00  |
| abc | vend_a | 2.00  |
| abc | vend_a | 3.00  |
| abc | vend_a | 4.00  |
| abc | vend_a | 5.00  |
| abc | vend_b | 1.00  |
| abc | vend_b | 2.00  |
| abc | vend_b | 3.00  |
| abc | vend_b | 4.00  |
| abc | vend_b | 5.00  |
| abc | vend_c | 1.00  |
| abc | vend_c | 2.00  |
| abc | vend_c | 3.00  |
| abc | vend_c | 4.00  |
| abc | vend_c | 5.00  |
+-----+--------+-------+
```

So after the select, I want this

```
    result
+-----+--------+-------+
| sku | vendor | price |
+-----+--------+-------+
| abc | vend_a | 1.00  |
| abc | vend_a | 2.00  |
| abc | vend_a | 3.00  |
| abc | vend_b | 1.00  |
| abc | vend_b | 2.00  |
| abc | vend_b | 3.00  |
| abc | vend_c | 1.00  |
| abc | vend_c | 2.00  |
| abc | vend_c | 3.00  |
+-----+--------+-------+
```

Have done some searching but found nothing that gives me this type of result. I appreciate your help.

Comment: This is something of a frequently asked question

Comment: I did considerable searching before posting, saw some answers with multiple tables, and single lowest prices, but not three lowest prices from each vendor on a single table. Forgive me if I missed an applicable similar answer. Can you point me there?

Comment: what SQL have you tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use variables to simulate `ROW_NUMBER` window function, not available in MySQL:

```
SELECT vendor, price
FROM (
  SELECT vendor, price,
      @rn := IF(@v = vendor, @rn + 1,
                IF(@v := vendor, 1, 1)) AS rn
  FROM offers
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @v := '') AS vars
  WHERE sku = 'abc'
  ORDER BY vendor, price) AS t
WHERE t.rn <= 3
```

Variable `@rn` enumerates records within each `vendor` partition. `@rn=1` corresponds to the record having the lowest price in the partition, `@rn=2` relates to next record, etc.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e641d/2)

Comment: @TimM I know, that's why I have used variables instead of `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: Thank you, sorry I understand now. I have tested this code, and it gives me the just the three lowest priced, not three lowest from each vendor.

Comment: @TimM There was initially a bug in the query, @v was initialized to 0, it should be set to ''.

Comment: This appears to work perfectly! Thank you very much.